# Over importing in Prefix.pch? (#ifdef __OBJC__)

Tags: objective-c, ios, import

So, if I'm remembering things correctly, anything imported in the Prefix.pch in my project will get imported into each of my new classes. However, by default, any NSObject subclasses import Foundation/Foundation.h and view subclasses import UIKit/UIKit.h in their respective headers.

Is this not an over import? Have I not essentially imported the Framework headers twice in my classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way to avoid the warning. Warnings are warnings and not errors because they may be wrong. In this case, ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1):

It's harmless. The `#import` preprocessor directive does nothing if the specified file has already been imported.

Comment: What about the fact that the .pch seem to import both UIKit.h and Foundation.h in any objective-c class? Will it actually import both into everything? Most NSObject subclasses don't have any need for UIKit.h, so why does it automatically import it - or at least seem to?